# Подсветка полей ввода красным, когда они не заполнены

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такая проблема: не могу задать полям ввода красную границу, когда они не заполнены. Надо сделать это с помощью js, но мой скрипт не работает. Вот сам код. Вся проблема в скрипте, где я сначала пытаюсь проверить пусто ли поле и если да, то присваиваю ему класс с красной границей.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    console.log(32)
    if ($('.rfield').val() != '') {
      // Если поле не пустое удаляем класс-указание
      $('.rfield').removeClass('empty_field');
    } else {
      // Если поле пустое добавляем класс-указание
      $(this).addClass('empty_field');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.empty-field {
  border: 2px red;
}
.form_box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.form_box label {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #444444;
  display: block;
}
.form_box input {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 7px 7px 8px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.form_box input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #07a6e6;
}
.form_box .btn_submit {
  border: none;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #07a6e6;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0;
}
.form_box .btn_submit:hover {
  background: #009ac2;
}
.form_box .btn_submit:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.form_box .btn_submit.disabled,
.form_box .btn_submit.disabled:hover {
  background: #afdde6;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form_box">

  <label for="user_name">Имя пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_name" />

  <label for="user_family">Фамилия пользователя</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_family" />

  <label for="user_phone">Телефон пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_phone" />

  <label for="user_work">Профессия пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_work" />

  <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn_submit disabled">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Опечатка: `empty_field` != `empty-field`.
2. Каждый `input` надо проверять индивидуально: `$('.form_box .rfield').each(function() {...`
3. Декларация класса `.empty_field` должна быть более конкретной, чем `.form_box input`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>rg</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <style type="text/css">
    .form_box input.empty_field {
      border-width: 2px;
      border-color: red;
    }
    .form_box {
      width: 300px;
      margin: 40px auto;
    }
    .form_box label {
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #444444;
      display: block;
    }
    .form_box input {
      display: block;
      border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #444444;
      padding: 7px 7px 8px;
      width: 250px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .form_box input:focus {
      outline: none;
      border-color: #07a6e6;
    }
    .form_box .btn_submit {
      border: none;
      width: 180px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #07a6e6;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #ffffff;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 35px;
      line-height: 28px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .form_box .btn_submit:hover {
      background: #009ac2;
    }
    .form_box .btn_submit:active {
      box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    .form_box .btn_submit.disabled,
    .form_box .btn_submit.disabled:hover {
      background: #afdde6;
      cursor: default;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="form_box">

    <label for="user_name">Имя пользователя:</label>
    <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_name" />

    <label for="user_family">Фамилия пользователя</label>
    <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_family" />

    <label for="user_phone">Телефон пользователя:</label>
    <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_phone" />

    <label for="user_work">Профессия пользователя:</label>
    <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_work" />

    <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn_submit disabled">Submit</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('document').ready(function() {
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
      $('.form_box .rfield').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
          console.log(32);
          // Если поле не пустое удаляем класс-указание
          $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
        } else {
          console.log(33);
          // Если поле пустое добавляем класс-указание
          $(this).addClass('empty_field');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю вам воспользоваться валидацией из коробки. HTML5 имеет нужные атрибуты для инпутов, а именно `required` в данном случае; также нам понадобится псевдокласс `:invalid` в CSS. Единственный минус такой валидации в том, что она происходит всегда, а не только после сабмита формы. Для того, чтобы этого избежать, надо после нажатия на кнопку всем инпутам с атрибутом `required` добавить класс `req`. А в CSS этому классу задать `.req:invalid` — и валидация на пустое значение инпута готова. Также можно добавить стили для правильно заполненных инпутов при помощи `.req:valid`.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('input[required]').addClass('req');
  });
});
```

```css
.form_box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.form_box label {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #444444;
  display: block;
}
.form_box input {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 7px 7px 8px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.form_box .req:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.form_box .req:valid {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.form_box input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #07a6e6;
}
.form_box .btn_submit {
  border: none;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #07a6e6;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0;
}
.form_box .btn_submit:hover {
  background: #009ac2;
}
.form_box .btn_submit:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.form_box .btn_submit.disabled,
.form_box .btn_submit.disabled:hover {
  background: #afdde6;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form_box">

  <label for="user_name">Имя пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_name" required />

  <label for="user_family">Фамилия пользователя</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_family" required />

  <label for="user_phone">Телефон пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_phone" required />

  <label for="user_work">Профессия пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_work" required />

  <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn_submit disabled">Submit</button>
</div>
```