# Вывод модального окна при незаполненном поле input

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Буду рад любым подсказкам в моей проблеме. У меня есть поля `input` и кнопка отправки. Мне необходимо, чтобы при попытке отправить данные, когда не все поля заполнены, всплывало модальное окно. Как можно это реализовать? Прилагаю весь код что у меня есть.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('.form_box .rfield').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != '') {
        console.log(32);
        // Если поле не пустое удаляем класс-указание
        $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
      } else {
        console.log(33);
        // Если поле пустое добавляем класс-указание
        $(this).addClass('empty_field');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.form_box input.empty_field {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
}
.form_box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.form_box label {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #444444;
  display: block;
}
.form_box input {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 7px 7px 8px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.form_box input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #07a6e6;
}
.form_box .btn_submit {
  border: none;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #07a6e6;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0;
}
.form_box .btn_submit:hover {
  background: #009ac2;
}
.form_box .btn_submit:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.form_box .btn_submit.disabled,
.form_box .btn_submit.disabled:hover {
  background: #afdde6;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form_box">

  <label for="user_name">Имя пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_name" />

  <label for="user_family">Фамилия пользователя</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_family" />

  <label for="user_phone">Телефон пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_phone" />

  <label for="user_work">Профессия пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_work" />

  <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn_submit disabled">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: на будущее: разносите код вашей страницы по блокам HTML, CSS, JS, не надо весь код вставлять в HTML-часть редактора. при раздельном виде читаемость вашего кода гораздо выше.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо вывода `alert` можете выводить что угодно.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('.form_box .rfield').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != '') {
        // Если поле не пустое удаляем класс-указание
        $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
      } else {
        // Если поле пустое добавляем класс-указание
        $(this).addClass('empty_field');
      }
    });

    if ($('.form_box .rfield.empty_field').length) alert('Не все поля формы заполнены верно.')
  });
});
```

```css
.form_box input.empty_field {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
}
.form_box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.form_box label {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #444444;
  display: block;
}
.form_box input {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 7px 7px 8px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.form_box input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #07a6e6;
}
.form_box .btn_submit {
  border: none;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #07a6e6;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0;
}
.form_box .btn_submit:hover {
  background: #009ac2;
}
.form_box .btn_submit:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.form_box .btn_submit.disabled,
.form_box .btn_submit.disabled:hover {
  background: #afdde6;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form_box">
  <label for="user_name">Имя пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_name" />

  <label for="user_family">Фамилия пользователя</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_family" />

  <label for="user_phone">Телефон пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_phone" />

  <label for="user_work">Профессия пользователя:</label>
  <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_work" />

  <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn_submit disabled">Submit</button>
</div>
```

P.S. пользуясь случаем, еще раз рекомендую посмотреть на [нативную реализацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624779/224820) проверки валидности формы, поддержка браузерами [весьма хорошая](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation).